# Unable to locate an image link using xpath

Tags: xpath

How to locate the image link within the element pasted below? I tried like this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
//img[@class]/@src
```

The element within which the image link is:

```
<div data-index="0" style="width: 300px; left: 0px; transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"><img alt="" class="" src="https://images.craigslist.org/00z0z_886m3prFkue_300x300.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: using HtmlAgilityPack parsing this worked:  //img[@src]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need attribute `class`.

Just use `//img/@src`

Comment: I used that expression in the first place but it couldn't locate the link either.

Comment: There is no ending `</img>` tag to the `<img>` tag in your input.

Comment: @svasa `img` element doesn't require closing tag